# How to number listings included by the \lstinputlisting command?

Tags: listings

I am trying to write a document displaying python codes, using the listing package with the \lstinputlisting command. It turns out that the counter "lstlisting" is not used or displayed, so that my listings are not numbered. I illustrate the problem with the following LaTeX code, where I use both the `\lstinputlisting` and the `\begin{lstlisting}\end{\lstlisting}` methods to include the same code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=Python,
title={Listing \arabic{lstlisting} -- File : \tt\lstname},
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{test.py}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption='test']
print("hello world")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

with the following result : listing is indeed normally numbered with the second method but not in the first. How to do that ?

[image: pdf output]

Comment: This is weird and probably a bug. As a workaround, you can create a macro to do the counter increment ` \newcommand{\mylstinputlisting}[1]{\stepcounter{lstlisting}\lstinputlisting{#1}}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I actually have used the solution you suggest, on a temporary basis, but then I do not benefit the `label` and `ref` mechanism to refer to a given listing, hence my question.

Comment: Right. But if you use a \refstepcounter{lstlisting} instead, you can have \label{} and \ref{}

Comment: I did not know that and I will try right away, thank you ! (and I'm still curious about my initial question)